# How to upsert an element in mongodb array?

Tags: mongodb

Suppose our document looks like this

```
{
   a:1,
   b:[
    {c:120,d:100},
    {c:121,d:110}
   ]
}
```

Now how could I upsert new objects in this array?
Suppose I want to perform update on the above document and add `{c:200,d:120}` to *b* so my expected result looks like this

```
{
   a:1,
   b:[
    {c:120,d:100},
    {c:121,d:110},
    {c:200,d:120}
   ]
}
```

Also the update will of $inc, meaning suppose I want to increment d by 200 if c is present(lets say c is 200 and it is already present in the above document), if not present then I want to upsert the document itself.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be achieved using the `$push` update command.

```
db.<Collection-Name>.updateOne({"a": 1}, {"$push": {"b": {"c":200, "d":120}}})
```

> Note: Use `$addToSet` if you don't want duplicates elements inside the array

UPDATE:

I don't think your precise requirement can't be achieved by a single command.

Your exact requirement can be achieved by the below script:

```
if (db.test9.findOne({"_id": ObjectId("5f19402abbc59a3864783fc7"), "b.c": 200}, {"_id": 1}) != null) {
    db.test9.updateOne({
        "_id": ObjectId("5f19402abbc59a3864783fc7"),
        "b.c": 200,
    }, {
        "$set": {
            "b.$.d": 120
        }
    })
} else {
    db.test9.updateOne({
        "_id": ObjectId("5f19402abbc59a3864783fc7"),
    }, {
        "$push": {
            "b": {
                "c":200, "d":120
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I want to update on the basis of value of c, if c is present then update the value of b, otherwise create new object in array.

Comment: The query I posted will do what you are looking for. If `c` is present, it will append `b` to the array. But, if `c` is not present, it will create a new object as required. Ping back if I understood the question wrongly

Comment: Sorry in the above comment I incorrectly mentioned b in place of d. IMO the query you mentioned will always push new object to the array b. But I want to update the already existing object in array if value of c matches. If for the given value of c no object exists in the array, then new object should be inserted (preferably an insert should be triggered using the upsert option). Hopefully, this clears up few things.

Comment: I don't think it is achievable by a single command. I have updated the answer with a script which does what you are looking for.

Comment: Yeah, it seems so. Thanks you your input.